# Can I capture photo and video uploads on my network?

Tags: backup, pi-hole

Brand new to the community but will be setting up pi hole this week on a pi zero w. I have an Android phone and am backing up all my photos and videos to Google photos. Wondering if I can somehow use the pi Zero that will be running pi hole to detect uploads to Google photos and automatically save them to a hard drive as an additional backup. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the connection to Google is encrypted ... you can't really intercept the data

Answer (score 1):

Pihole would only record DNS queries and currently offers no simple hooks to act when specific names are being resolved. With secure DNS, with caching and with applications ignoring/circumventing DNS server settings you may not even catch every time a domain is contacted.

To explicitly answer the question: you cannot (easily) intercept data transfer to modern secure services such as Google photos. This is a good thing, you wouldn't want others to intercept your data.

What you CAN do is create a local backup from Google photos *after* your data has been uploaded. A quick search brought up [gphotos-sync](https://github.com/gilesknap/gphotos-sync), there are probably more/similar solutions around.